# How to delete all records from table except top 5

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am writing a simple quiz game in python and I need to print out the top 5 scores at the end of the game. I am using sqlite. I have a table for the top scores and I have worked out how to get the top scores but because I only need the top 5 scores I would like to delete all the records with scores lower than the top 5. Is this possible with an SQL statement or would I need to write it in python.

Thanks

Comment: Could there be two or more scores in the top 5 which happened to be tied?  What you really want to use here is `ROW_NUMBER`, but that doesn't exist in SQLite AFAIK.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you can fake it by left joining the table to itself where score < score - the cartesian product would result in an increasing number of rows for reducing scores

Comment: You should post that as an answer if you think it's workable.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen versions >= 3.25 from SQLite has `row_number` feature :-)
https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html#built_in_window_functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
DELETE
FROM yourTable
WHERE score NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT score
                    FROM yourTable
                    ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5);
```

This answer would be robust to ties in the top 5, but would have the behavior of returning possibly more than 5 records, with all those records bearing a score in the top 5 overall.

If `ROW_NUMBER` were available, we could try something like:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, score, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

DELETE
FROM yourTable
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM cte WHERE rn <= 5);
```

Again, there is the question of how to handle ties.  You might actually want to use `DENSE_RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: How come you didn't use id? `id not in(select id order by score)`

Comment: @CaiusJard The rankings happening here are based on the score, not some other `id`.

Comment: I get that, but what if there are only scores 1 and 2 - no data will be deleted?

Comment: Yes...those two values are in the top 5, why should anything be deleted?

Comment: I meant if there were 10 rows with scores: 1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2 then after the delete op the table will still have 10 rows.. I'm curious why you're using a non-primary key to identify rows to delete, when the desired end result is to have a table with 5 rows of the highest scores (my interpretation) and deleting everything that is not id <list of 5 PKs> will achieve that? I suppose this is about tie-handling; you're keeping ties even if it means having more than 5 winners, I'm removing them to result in only 5 winners (and bad luck to Zacharia Zedson who scored equal 5th place with Adam Adams)

Comment: The first option worked perfectly. Thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 1):

I have a strong aversion to `NOT IN` with a subquery, because it does not behave as expected if *any* of the `score` values are negative.  So I would recommend:

```
DELETE FROM t
WHERE score < (SELECT DISTINCT t2.score
                FROM t2
                ORDER BY t2.score DESC
                LIMIT 1 OFFSET 4
               );
```